# Fabric JS: sync position of object after pan/zoom across two instances

Tags: javascript, canvas, zooming, fabricjs, pan

Fabric JS question.

**SCREENSHOT** [this is what my Fabric JS app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aR5A.png)

**CODEPEN**  https://codepen.io/zaynbuksh/pen/VVKRxj?editors=0011 (*alt-click-drag* to pan, *scroll-wheel* to zoom)

**TLDR;** How do I get the line to stick after panning and zooming a few times?

---

I am developing a Fabric JS app for labeling images of specimens. As part of this, people want to be able to zoom in on what each label is pointing at. I have been asked to make the labels remain visible when the specimen image is zoomed in. From research, people recommend two canvases stacked on top of each other.

I have created two Fabric JS canvas instances, layered on top of each other. The canvas at the bottom holds a background image that can be zoomed and panned, the canvas above it shows a pointer-line/label that is not zoomed (to keep the label visible at all times).

At first everything works - the line stays in sync with the image when I pan and zoom the **first** time only. I get problems with syncing the line to the image after that.

**The problem manifests when I pan then zoom *two* or more times.** The problem repeats each time I pan and then zoom i.e. the line moves when I zoom, but then stays in sync when I pan, moves again when I zoom again, pans normally and so on...

---

(Pan is handled by alt-click-drag, Zoom is handled by scroll wheel)

```js
/*

  "mouse:wheel" event is where zooms are handled
  "mouse:move" event is where panning is handled

*/

// create Fabric JS canvas'
var labelsCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("labelsCanvas");
var specimenCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("specimenCanvas");
//set defaults
var startingPositionForLine = 100;
const noZoom = 1;
var wasPanned = false;
var panY2 = startingPositionForLine;
var panX2 = startingPositionForLine;
var zoomY2 = startingPositionForLine;
var zoomX2 = startingPositionForLine;
// set starting zoom for specimen canvas
var specimenZoom = noZoom;

/* 

  Add pointer, label and background image into canvas

*/

// create a pointer line
var line = new fabric.Line([150, 35, panX2, panY2], {
  fill: "red",
  stroke: "red",
  strokeWidth: 3,
  strokeDashArray: [5, 2],
  // selectable: false,
  evented: false
});

// create text label
var text = new fabric.Text("Label 1", {
  left: 100,
  top: 0,
  // selectable: false,
  evented: false,
  backgroundColor: "red"
});

// add both into "Labels" canvas
labelsCanvas.add(text);
labelsCanvas.add(line);

// add a background image into Specimen canvas
fabric.Image.fromURL(
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Skull_brain_human_normal.svg",
  function(oImg) {
    oImg.left = 0;
    oImg.top = 0;
    oImg.scaleToWidth(300);
    oImg.scaleToHeight(300);
    specimenCanvas.add(oImg);
  }
);

/* 

  Handle mouse events

*/

// zoom the specimen image canvas via a mouse scroll-wheel event
labelsCanvas.on("mouse:wheel", function(opt) {
  // scroll value e.g. 5, 6 -1, -18
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  // zoom level in specimen
  var zoom = specimenCanvas.getZoom();

  console.log("zoom ", zoom);

  // make zoom smaller
  zoom = zoom + delta / 200;
  // use sane defaults for zoom
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;

  // create new zoom value
  zoomX2 = panX2 * zoom;
  zoomY2 = panY2 * zoom;
  // save the zoom
  specimenZoom = zoom;
  // set the specimen canvas zoom
  specimenCanvas.setZoom(zoom);

  // move line to sync it with the zoomed image
  line.set({
    x2: zoomX2,
    y2: zoomY2
  });

  console.log("zoomed line ", line.x2);

  // render the changes
  this.requestRenderAll();
  // block default mouse behaviour
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();

  console.log(labelsCanvas.viewportTransform[4]);

  // stuff I've tried to fix errors
  line.setCoords();
  specimenCanvas.calcOffset();

});

// pan the canvas
labelsCanvas.on("mouse:move", function(opt) {
  if (this.isDragging) {
    
    // pick up the click and drag event
    var e = opt.e;
    
    // sync the label position with the panning
    text.left = text.left + (e.clientX - this.lastPosX);

    var x2ToUse;
    var y2ToUse;

    // UNZOOMED canvas is being panned
    if (specimenZoom === noZoom) {
      x2ToUse = panX2;
      y2ToUse = panY2;
      
      // move the image using the difference between 
      // the current position and last known position 
      line.set({
        x1: line.x1 + (e.clientX - this.lastPosX),
        y1: line.y1,
        x2: x2ToUse + (e.clientX - this.lastPosX),
        y2: y2ToUse + (e.clientY - this.lastPosY)
      });
      
      // set the new panning value
      panX2 = line.x2;
      panY2 = line.y2;
      
      // stuff I've tried
      // zoomX2 = line.x2;
      // zoomY2 = line.y2;
    } 
    
    // ZOOMED canvas is being panned
    else 
    {
      x2ToUse = zoomX2;
      y2ToUse = zoomY2;
      
      // stuff I've tried
      // x2ToUse = panX2;
      // y2ToUse = panY2;

      // move the image using the difference between 
      // the current position and last known ZOOMED position 
      line.set({
        x1: line.x1 + (e.clientX - this.lastPosX),
        y1: line.y1,
        x2: x2ToUse + (e.clientX - this.lastPosX),
        y2: y2ToUse + (e.clientY - this.lastPosY)
      });
      
      zoomX2 = line.x2;
      zoomY2 = line.y2;
    }

    // hide label/pointer when it is out of view
    if (text.left < 0 || line.y2 < 35) {
      text.animate("opacity", "0", {
        duration: 15,
        onChange: labelsCanvas.renderAll.bind(labelsCanvas)
      });
      line.animate("opacity", "0", {
        duration: 15,
        onChange: labelsCanvas.renderAll.bind(labelsCanvas)
      });
    } 
    // show label/pointer when it is in view
    else 
    {
      text.animate("opacity", "1", {
        duration: 25,
        onChange: labelsCanvas.renderAll.bind(labelsCanvas)
      });
      line.animate("opacity", "1", {
        duration: 25,
        onChange: labelsCanvas.renderAll.bind(labelsCanvas)
      });
    }


    specimenCanvas.viewportTransform[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX;

    specimenCanvas.viewportTransform[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY;

    this.requestRenderAll();
    specimenCanvas.requestRenderAll();

    this.lastPosX = e.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = e.clientY;
  }

  console.log(line.x2);

  wasPanned = true;
});

labelsCanvas.on("mouse:down", function(opt) {
  var evt = opt.e;
  if (evt.altKey === true) {
    this.isDragging = true;
    this.selection = false;
    this.lastPosX = evt.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = evt.clientY;
  }
});

labelsCanvas.on("mouse:up", function(opt) {
  this.isDragging = false;
  this.selection = true;
});
```

```css
.canvas-container {
    position: absolute!important;
    left: 0!important;
    top: 0!important;
}

.canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid red 1px;
}

.label-canvas {
    z-index: 2;
}

.specimen-canvas {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<h1>
  Dual canvas test
</h1>
<div style="position: relative; height: 300px">
  <canvas class="canvas specimen-canvas" id="specimenCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <canvas class="canvas label-canvas" id="labelsCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note, I think you're overcomplicating things a little bit. You don't really need to store `panX`/`panY` and `zoomX`/`zoomY` (zoomed pan as I've guessed) separately, they're already there in your `line`'s coordinates. Just saying, because they've probably contributed to the confusion/debugging. The core idea of a fix, however, is that you should multiply your `line`'s coordinates not by the whole zoom value but by the `newZoom / previousZoom` ratio. I've updated your snippet, it seems to work as expected:

```js
/*

  "mouse:wheel" event is where zooms are handled
  "mouse:move" event is where panning is handled

*/

// create Fabric JS canvas'
var labelsCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("labelsCanvas");
var specimenCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("specimenCanvas");
//set defaults
var startingPositionForLine = 100;
const noZoom = 1;
var wasPanned = false;
var panY2 = startingPositionForLine;
var panX2 = startingPositionForLine;
var zoomY2 = startingPositionForLine;
var zoomX2 = startingPositionForLine;
// set starting zoom for specimen canvas
var specimenZoom = noZoom;

var prevZoom = noZoom;

/* 

  Add pointer, label and background image into canvas

*/

// create a pointer line
var line = new fabric.Line([150, 35, panX2, panY2], {
  fill: "red",
  stroke: "red",
  strokeWidth: 3,
  strokeDashArray: [5, 2],
  // selectable: false,
  evented: false
});

// create text label
var text = new fabric.Text("Label 1", {
  left: 100,
  top: 0,
  // selectable: false,
  evented: false,
  backgroundColor: "red"
});

// add both into "Labels" canvas
labelsCanvas.add(text);
labelsCanvas.add(line);

// add a background image into Specimen canvas
fabric.Image.fromURL(
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Skull_brain_human_normal.svg",
  function(oImg) {
    oImg.left = 0;
    oImg.top = 0;
    oImg.scaleToWidth(300);
    oImg.scaleToHeight(300);
    specimenCanvas.add(oImg);
  }
);

window.specimenCanvas = specimenCanvas

/* 

  Handle mouse events

*/

// zoom the specimen image canvas via a mouse scroll-wheel event
labelsCanvas.on("mouse:wheel", function(opt) {
  // scroll value e.g. 5, 6 -1, -18
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  // zoom level in specimen
  var zoom = specimenCanvas.getZoom();
  var lastZoom = zoom

  // make zoom smaller
  zoom = zoom + delta / 200;
  // use sane defaults for zoom
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;

  // save the zoom
  specimenZoom = zoom;
  // set the specimen canvas zoom
  specimenCanvas.setZoom(zoom);

  // move line to sync it with the zoomed image
  var zoomRatio = zoom / lastZoom
  console.log('zoom ratio: ', zoomRatio)
  line.set({
    x2: line.x2 * zoomRatio,
    y2: line.y2 * zoomRatio
  });
  
  // console.log("zoomed line ", line.x2);

  // render the changes
  this.requestRenderAll();
  // block default mouse behaviour
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();

  // console.log(labelsCanvas.viewportTransform[4]);

  // stuff I've tried to fix errors
  line.setCoords();
  specimenCanvas.calcOffset();
});

// pan the canvas
labelsCanvas.on("mouse:move", function(opt) {
  if (this.isDragging) {
    
    // pick up the click and drag event
    var e = opt.e;
    
    // sync the label position with the panning
    text.left = text.left + (e.clientX - this.lastPosX);

    // UNZOOMED canvas is being panned
    if (specimenZoom === noZoom) {
      x2ToUse = panX2;
      y2ToUse = panY2;
      
      // move the image using the difference between 
      // the current position and last known position 
      line.set({
        x1: line.x1 + (e.clientX - this.lastPosX),
        y1: line.y1,
        x2: line.x2 + (e.clientX - this.lastPosX),
        y2: line.y2 + (e.clientY - this.lastPosY)
      });
      
      // stuff I've tried
      // zoomX2 = line.x2;
      // zoomY2 = line.y2;
    } 
    
    // ZOOMED canvas is being panned
    else 
    {
      // move the image using the difference between 
      // the current position and last known ZOOMED position 
      line.set({
        x1: line.x1 + (e.clientX - this.lastPosX),
        y1: line.y1,
        x2: line.x2 + (e.clientX - this.lastPosX),
        y2: line.y2 + (e.clientY - this.lastPosY)
      });
    }

    // hide label/pointer when it is out of view
    if (text.left < 0 || line.y2 < 35) {
      text.animate("opacity", "0", {
        duration: 15,
        onChange: labelsCanvas.renderAll.bind(labelsCanvas)
      });
      line.animate("opacity", "0", {
        duration: 15,
        onChange: labelsCanvas.renderAll.bind(labelsCanvas)
      });
    } 
    // show label/pointer when it is in view
    else 
    {
      text.animate("opacity", "1", {
        duration: 25,
        onChange: labelsCanvas.renderAll.bind(labelsCanvas)
      });
      line.animate("opacity", "1", {
        duration: 25,
        onChange: labelsCanvas.renderAll.bind(labelsCanvas)
      });
    }


    specimenCanvas.viewportTransform[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX;

    specimenCanvas.viewportTransform[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY;

    this.requestRenderAll();
    specimenCanvas.requestRenderAll();

    this.lastPosX = e.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = e.clientY;
    prevZoom = specimenCanvas.getZoom()
  }

  // console.log(line.x2);

  wasPanned = true;
});

labelsCanvas.on("mouse:down", function(opt) {
  var evt = opt.e;
  if (evt.altKey === true) {
    this.isDragging = true;
    this.selection = false;
    this.lastPosX = evt.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = evt.clientY;
  }
});

labelsCanvas.on("mouse:up", function(opt) {
  this.isDragging = false;
  this.selection = true;
});
```

```css
.canvas-container {
    position: absolute!important;
    left: 0!important;
    top: 0!important;
}

.canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid red 1px;
}

.label-canvas {
    z-index: 2;
}

.specimen-canvas {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<h1>
  Dual canvas test
</h1>
<div style="position: relative; height: 300px">
  <canvas class="canvas specimen-canvas" id="specimenCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <canvas class="canvas label-canvas" id="labelsCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks shkaper, you're a champ! If I understand correctly, you're advising to abandon the variables and instead get those values out of the line.x2/y2 directly because the variables are an unnecessary step? That makes sense. I'm sorry my vote doesn't show up here because I'm still new, but I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @zaynbuksh you're welcome, I'm glad it helped! *If I understand correctly, you're advising to abandon the variables and instead get those values out of the line.x2/y2 directly because the variables are an unnecessary step?* That's right. But that's just how I felt, having spent some time looking at the code.